# runs unless I click on the button

Tags: javascript

here is my code in a page javascript, my problem that the first time I click on the button and I go to the second page and all goes well, but when I returned to this page another time, function of button `$("consulter").live('click',function(e)` runs unless I click on the button

how can i resolve this problem

```
 $('#lbtn').append('<input type="button" value="Consulter" id="consulter" >');


$("consulter").live('click',function(e)
         {

    alert("eere");
        var sel_id_rub = $('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id');//ID of Rubrique

         window.localStorage.setItem("id_rub", sel_id_rub);       //Id Rubrique
         liste_Phrase();



     }
     );
```

Comment: 0/10 accepted, no answer from me...

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle or something like that with the HTML and JS showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is wrong, but I don't know if that is the problem:

```
$("#consulter").live('click',function(e)
```

Comment: No, it's a typo but it is not that